# How to add one year and two days to a date in mysql

Tags: mysql, date

I want to add **one year and two days** to a date in mysql

I'm tring this code, but it is not working.

Please help me. Thank you.

**DATE_ADD(vehicle_master.expire_date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR +2 DAY) AS expire_date,**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use twice `date_add` instead:

```
mysql> select DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD('2016-04-01', INTERVAL 1 YEAR), INTERVAL 2 DAY);
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD('2016-04-01', INTERVAL 1 YEAR), INTERVAL 2 DAY) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2017-04-03                                                        |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't combine intervals in that way.

To do this, you would:

DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(vehicle_master.expire_date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR), 2 DAY) as somedate