# How do I add one year to this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, date, date-format

```
    SELECT date_format(CURDATE(), '%e-%b-%y');
```

This spits out the date to be 27-Dec-22 and I simply need to run another query so it shows 27-Dec-23

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add one year and two days to a date in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36441050/how-to-add-one-year-and-two-days-to-a-date-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may directly add one year using `INTERVAL` syntax:

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 year, '%e-%b-%y');  -- 27-Dec-23
```

Comment: Tim, you are the man!

Answer (score 1):

use **date_add** and **interval**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR), '%e-%b-%y')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [INTERVAL](https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-interval#:%7E:text=MySQL%20interval%20is%20an%20operator,INTERVAL%20expr%20unit) in this case

```
SELECT date_format(CURDATE()+ INTERVAL 1 YEAR, '%e-%b-%y')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(your date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR), '%e-%b-%y')
```